# Solve the equation using Lambert's W function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

How could I possibly solve for $x$ in the following equation using the $W$ function?

$$\frac{1-x}xe^x = C$$ for some constant number, $C$?

I prepared the left-hand term as in the following equation hoping that I am closer to formulate it using the $W$ function, but ended up with more $xs$ on the right-hand side.

$$xe^x= C \cdot \frac{x^2}{1-x}$$

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I tried $C=5$ with Wolfram alpha and received only a numerical solution, not one using the Lambert-w-function. Indication what we actually need numerical methods here.

Comment: Maybe you can use the series expansion for $e^x\cdot \frac{1-x}{x}$. Using the first two summands of the series expansion you´ll get an quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, there is no solution(s) in terms of the usual Lambert function.

However, writing the equation as $$e^{-x}=\frac{1-x}{Cx}$$ solutions could be expressed in terms of the generalized  Lambert function.

You could be, at least out of curiosity, be interested by [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf).

Numerical methods would be required (Newton being the simplest).

However, if $C$ is not too large, we could use Pade approximants built around $x=1$ and get
$$\frac{ (1-x)}{x}e^x =-e (x-1)\frac {1+\frac{18}{35}  (x-1)+\frac{13}{140}  (x-1)^2 } {1+\frac{18 }{35}(x-1)-\frac{57}{140} (x-1)^2+\frac{8}{105}
   (x-1)^3 }$$ which would reduce the problem to a cubic equation in $y=x-1$.
$$(32 C+39 e) y^3-(171 C-216 e) y^2+(216 C+420 e) y+420 C=0$$ which has only one real root if $C>0$.

For illustration purposes, I produced below the approximate solution (from the cubic) as well as the exact solution for a few values of $C$.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
C & \text{approximate} &\text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.659045 & 0.659046 \\
 2 & 0.436051 & 0.436086 \\
 3 & 0.313007 & 0.313142 \\
 4 & 0.241166 & 0.241428 \\
 5 & 0.195250 & 0.195635 \\
 6 & 0.163666 & 0.164159 \\
 7 & 0.140703 & 0.141290 \\
 8 & 0.123290 & 0.123957 \\
 9 & 0.109647 & 0.110382 \\
 10 & 0.098677 & 0.099471
\end{array}
\right)$$